# echo (float)12,3; versus echo (float)"12,3"; - why the difference?

Tags: php

I recently got a bit surprised when I saw this casting result.

```
echo (float)12,3; 
echo "\n"; 
echo (float)"12,3";
```

The first will give us `123` and the second `12`.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple

```
echo (float)12,3;
```

Means you are sending two values to echo as a comma separated list of parameters. `12` and `3`, which echoed together look like `123`. You can echo hundreds of things together in 1 call, PHP doesn't mind.

```
echo (float)"12,3";
```

You are sending a *string* `"12,3"` to echo ***after*** casting it to a `float`. When its converted to float it becomes 12 which you see being printed.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that PHP is seeing `12,3` as `12` and `3`. PHP simply removes the non-numeric character.

```
var_dump(12,3);
int(12) 
int(3)
```

`"12,3"` is a string and PHP is throwing out everything after the first non-numeric character.

```
echo (int)"12b3"; // also outputs 12
```

Answer (score 1):

In php, `,` is also a concatenation operator, so `12,3` is interpreted as `123`.

But,

`"12,3"` is a string and `,` is treated as character, so converting string to float resulting in `12`

Comment: Again wrong. Thats not the reason. `12,3` means 2 values are being sent to `echo` which it can handle just fine. And No, `,` is ***not*** a concatenation operator in PHP

Comment: Ahh, indeed I completely forgot that we can do echo $var1,$var2 - this explains it, thank you! @Hanky 웃 Panky - just out of curiosity, what's the difference between comma being concatenation operator (like a dot) and sending two values separately?

Comment: Because comma isnt a concatenation operator it will result in a parse error for any other command. For example `$a=4,5;` will generate syntax error. The reason it is fine for echo is because echo is a construct which can take a comma separated list of values.